# Creating subgroups in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

Suppose we have a group `G`:

```
F := FreeGroup(3);
G := F / [F.1^3, F.2^4, F.3^5, F.1*F.2*F.1^-1];
```

(the relations don't matter). How do we get a subgroup of `G` generated by `G.1` and `G.2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post was full of typos, which might account for your problems. You can put:

```
H := Subgroup(G, [G.1,G.2]);
```

Or, for more general situations:

```
gens := GeneratorsOfGroup(G);;
H := Subgroup(G, [gens[1], gens[2]] );
```

Comment: The problem is, when I use either of those, I get 'Error, Variable: 'G' must have a value'. (or Variable 'gens')

Comment: As I said before, your original post, before I edited it was full of typos. You had used f.1 rather than F.1 some of the time, for example. Try copying and pasting from the edited version.

Answer (score 3):

[According to the manual,](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7BA181CA81D785BB) simply use `Subgroup(G, [G.1, G.2]);`.

Comment: This does not work. I get 'Error, Variable: 'G' must have a value'.

Comment: Your problem, then, @ranger281, is likely to be in your definition of `G`; having said that, though, you could try `[F.1, F.2]` instead of `[G.1, G.2]`. As Prof. Derek Holt suggests in his answer, defining `gens` as `GeneratorsOfGroup(G)` might help, but - as you say - that's not working either, so I still think your issue is with `G` itself.